# $f:X \to Y $ is continuous on $X$ and $(X, d_1) $ is compact. Then $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous on $X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, proof-explanation

$(X, d_1) $ and $(Y, d_2) $be two metric spaces.

$f:X \to Y $ is continuous on $X$ and $(X, d_1) $ is compact.

Claim: $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

My attempt:

Suppose $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Then, $\exists (x_n) \text { and } (y_n) $ two sequence of points in $X$ with $$d_1(x_n , y_n) \to 0$$ but $$d_2 (f(x_n) , f(y_n) )  \nrightarrow  0$$

Now, since $(X,d_1)$ is compact $(x_n) $has a convergent subsequence  $(x_{n_{k}}) $ and suppose converges to $x$ in the space $(X, d_1) $.

Then, for the increasing sequence $(n_k) \subset {\mathbb{N}}$,

\begin{align}d_1(y_{n_k}, x) &\le d_1(y_{n_k}, x_{n_k})+ d_1(x_{n_k}, x)\\ &\rightarrow 0 [ k \to \infty]\end{align}

Hence, $(x_{n_k}) \text { and } (y_{n_k})$ be two sequence in $X$ and both converges to $x$ in $(X, d_1) $

Since,$f$ is continuous at $x\in X$, $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(x) \leftarrow f(y_{n_k})$

Hence, $d_2(f(x_{n_k}), f(y_{n_k})\to 0$

Now, choosing the positive integer $ n =n_k $ then there doesn't exists any $\epsilon >0 $ and $k>n$ such that $d_2(f(x_{k}), f(y_{k}))\ge \epsilon > 0$

Hence, it is a contradiction.

Is the proof correct?

Is there any logical mistake?

Please add some details to clarify more. Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment on the structure of the proof: it goes like: 1. Assume X is not true. 2. Direct proof of X. 3. This contradicts the assumption, so X must be true.  ---  You should just skip steps 1. and 3.

Comment: Sir, please write down the correct proof. It will help me a lot

Comment: Skimming over your proof, it does look correct. It's not wrong to make unnecessary steps. It's just bad style, so to say. You should try to isolate the unnecessary steps yourself, if you want to improve yourself. It'll give you a better understanding of how to approach such proofs than if you were just told to cut out this or that.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the proof, it looks correct. I would expand a bit the triangle inequality that allows you to say $d_2(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}) \rightarrow 0$.

Just a side note. What you are exploiting is actually sequential compactness, which is equivalent to compactness (the open cover definition) in metric spaces: I would justify a bit this passage.